# Python Error en crear una sola base de dataframe que adjunte todas

Tags: python

Busco Crear una base dataframe adjuntando todas las que salen del for anidado en otro for, pero no lo consigo.

Alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
k = RefDu(BasePro1.Marca)
print(k)
for i in k:
    dfMarcas = BasePro1[BasePro1['Marca']==i]
    #dfMarcas.to_excel(mpath+'/Data/PronMarca/Marca'+str(i)+'.xlsx',index=False)
    print(i)
    h = RefDu(BasePro1.ReferenciaProveedor_x)
    for j in h:
        
        df = BasePro1[BasePro1['ReferenciaProveedor_x']==j]
        print(df)
        
        #print(df)
        #df.to_excel(mpath+'/Data/MMMMMM'+str(i)+str(j)+'.xlsx',index=False)
        
#model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(df, order=(1, 1, 0))
#df.to_excel(mpath+'/Data/SabanaComprasAgrupST_'+str(i)+'.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: Buen día ¿Qué error te sale? ¿En qué estás atorado? ¿Puedes incluir los datos de tus `dataframe`? Sin información sería muy difícil adivinar por donde empezar

Comment: Hola. Pues es que cuando termina de correo solo me guarda una sola data en el variable o dataframe df. y necesito que me adjunte todas las tablas que salen en una sola.